# How to Email include Notes link to open xpages client

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have problem when sending a notes link to an email in order to open it directly from email client. Does the link i created is invalid? May i know which is a correct way of sending notes link open xpages page?

**Question 1. How to open Document in xpages with document ID by clicking notes link?**

one way: i understand is at the form Display xpages. May i know still got other way to do it?

[image]

**Question 2. How to open Xpages Page without document ID for example is like the page that contain view.**

My doclink is write as:

```
var doclink="notes://"+server+"/"+dname.replace(/(\\)/g, "/")+"/"+document1.getDocument().getUniversalID()+"/Request_Form.xsp?OpenXpages"
```

result come out for that link:
[image]

My viewlink is write as:

```
var viewlink ="notes://" +server+"/"+dname.replace(/(\\)/g, "/")+"/"+"Request_View.xsp?OpenXPage"
```

result come out for that link:
[image]

My server and database name as below

[image]

Below will be my script of sending email

```
var setdoc:NotesDocument = database.getProfileDocument("System Setting", "");
var server = setdoc.getItemValueString("MailDBSvr");
var dname = setdoc.getItemValueString("MailDbPath");
var web = setdoc.getItemValueString("InternetAddress");


var maildoc:NotesDocument = database.createDocument()//mdb.createDocument()  //database.createDocument()
maildoc.replaceItemValue("Form", "Memo");
maildoc.replaceItemValue("Subject","Request for Email Account By "+document1.getItemValueString('Name'));
session.setConvertMime(false);
var stream = session.createStream();
stream.writeText("<html><body>");

stream.writeText("<p>Dear " + "department reviewer" + ",</p>");
stream.writeText('<p>Kindly review this request by '+document1.getItemValueString('Name')+" on "+I18n.toString(@Today(), 'dd/MM/yyyy')+ ",</p>");

//  open in web (http://devsvr1.pcs.com.my/CN=ServerOne/O=dev!!Brooke%5CBrooke.nsf/Request_Form.xsp?databaseName=CN=ServerOne/O=dev!!Brooke%5CBrooke.nsf&documentId=5FBA577C3DF795AB4825819400274B0A&action=editDocument)
stream.writeText("<p>Please click "+"<a href='http://"+web+"/"+
database.getServer()+"!!"+
XSPUrl.encodeParameter(dname, "UTF-8") +
"/"+"Request_Form.xsp?databaseName="+server+"!!"+
XSPUrl.encodeParameter(dname,"UTF-8") +
"&documentId="+document1.getDocument().getUniversalID()+
"&action=editDocument'>here</a> to open requisition form</p>")


//  open in notes client (notes://server/path/database.nsf/pagename.xsp?openXpage)
var doclink="notes://"+server+"/"+dname.replace(/(\\)/g, "/")+"/"+document1.getDocument().getUniversalID()+"/Request_Form.xsp?OpenXpages"

stream.writeText("<p><a href='"+doclink+"'>Click Here</a> if you are in the Notes Client. Thank you.</p>");

stream.writeText("<p>Or</p>");

//  open in web (http://devsvr1.pcs.com.my/brooke/brooke.nsf/Request_View.xsp)

stream.writeText("<p>Click <a href='http://"+web+"/"+dname.replace(/(\\)/g, "/")+"/"+"Request_View.xsp?'>here</a> to view all requisitions.</p>");

//  Open in notes Client
//  @URLOpen("notes://server/Path/database.nsf/XPageName.xsp?OpenXPage")
var viewlink ="notes://" +server+"/"+dname.replace(/(\\)/g, "/")+"/"+"Request_View.xsp?OpenXPage"

stream.writeText("<p><a href='"+viewlink+"'>Click Here</a> if you are in the Notes Client. Thank you.</p>");

stream.writeText("<p> ***THIS IS AN AUTOMATED MESSAGE - PLEASE DO NOT REPLY DIRECTLY TO THIS EMAIL***</p>");

stream.writeText("</body></html>");
var body = maildoc.createMIMEEntity("Body");
body.setContentFromText(stream, "text/html;charset=UTF-8", 1725);
stream.close();
maildoc.closeMIMEEntities(true);
session.setConvertMime(true);

maildoc.replaceItemValue("SendTo",document1.getItemValue("Dep_rev"));       

maildoc.send(); 
document1.getDocument().computeWithForm(true,true);
```

**New update:**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the way you handle the server name. [Notes URLs](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/notes-urls) don't use the full canonical name for servers.

So change `CN=ServerOne/O=Dev` to something the `notes://` protocol does support. You could use:

- the shortened name `ServerOne%2FDev` (use @Name[Abbreviate] and replace / with %2f)
- the Common name `ServerOne` (use @Name[CN])
- the DNS name `www.yourserver.com`
- the IP address: `165.34.11.34`

In all cases you need to make sure that the server name gets properly resolved by the Notes client:

- For the shortened name a connection document would do the trick (unless its the default server, then it is auto).
- For the Common name it is either a connection document or the DNS resolved it (intranet DNS)
- for the DNS name, its DNS (doh)
- You really don't want to use IP addresses, but you could

Hope that helps

Comment: Notes://ServerOne/dev/Brooke/Brooke.nsf/unid/Request_Form.xsp?OpenXpages

Do this link is valid? as in notes URL page, i cant find open xpages link sample

Comment: Unid isn't part of an xsp URL. The easiest way: just open the document and in form properties specify to open an xpage for that form. For new docs use ....nsf/xpagename.xsp

Comment: I use new docs style, it give me an error message, Already update image in question :

Link: notes://ServerOne/dev/Brooke/Brooke.nsf/Request_View.xsp

Comment: That string doesn't look right. Use the format notes://DNS-name-from-server-doc/dB.nsf/.... basically: use the web link and just swap https:// with Notes:// - If the web link works the Notes link should too